# can use login user as parameter for shared dataset in SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

can anyone help me with my issue,
how can get login userName in report server and pass it to a shared dataset to filter a report query for my parameter? (Basically i managed to get the user"User!userID" and add it as parameter on my shared dataset but, it runs fine in Visual studio and all the dataset that depend on that user are populating but when i deploy the report all the parameter that depend the user does not populate)

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this by making the dataset that depends on the User built in parameter, a shared dataset. Before I did this I had the same problem as you in that the user ID was not picked up.